# Unable to install .ipa file on MaaS360 enabled devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ipa

My client is unable to install ipa file on MaaS360 enabled devices
what might be the reason here
i have created ipa file using client developer certificates and for testing purpose they added our device udid to their portal.
here i can able to install ipa file using same certificates.
my concern here why it is not possible for client.
he is saying install option is disabled in itunes.
please let me know the reason.
Does MaaS60 enablement is an issue or what?

Answer (score 0):

Hi，I deploy maas360 system too,my version is 2.4.

I found MaaS360 sign iOS app tool is changed at this version,try to use new version tool.

New version tool can sign iOS app extension.

May it can help to you .